# Floating Variable Number of DIVs to the Center

Tags: html, css

I defined two CSS classes that set the background to an image (shown below).  One is a yellow block, and another is a grey block.

```
.block-gray { background: url('grey.gif'); width: 15px; height: 3px; }
```

[image]

```
.block-yellow { background: url('yellow.gif'); width: 15px; height: 3px; }
```

[image]

---

What I want to be able to do is to define a variable number of div's using one of the classes above, and have them horizontally stacked, and centered within a larger container.

So if I defined 3 blocks like so:

```
<div>
   <!-- The # of these is variable, and not necessarily fixed at 3 -->
   <div class="block-yellow"></div>
   <div class="block-yellow"></div>
   <div class="block-grey"></div>
<div>
```

Then I would like them to be centered within the outer div, no matter how many inner divs there are.  I can use float:left to stack them horizontally, but I'm not sure how to keep them centered.

|     [image] [image] [image]     |

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.container    { text-align: center; }
.block-yellow { display: inline-block; }
```

and you might want to reset that text-align:

```
.block-yellow { text-align: left; }
```

Comment: Just be aware that `inline-block` has [limited support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) in IE < 8.

Answer (score 0):

well, don't use float:left; instead, use display:block and set the outer div as text-align:center

Comment: Thanks, but how would display:block allow the divs to flow horizontally?

Comment: It won't; you need "display: inline-block" (see my answer)